# Go Regex not matching

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to extract a JSON object from a custom payload.

My regex is working fine here: https://regex101.com/r/G5lBDC/1/

But Go returns no matches

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`/payload:\\"(.+?)\\\\\\"\\\\/g`)
rawResponse := "version:1 response:<status:200 message:\"OK\" payload:\"{\\\"id\\\":\\\"ll2.card_4U45pAWUMCLhsu\\\",\\\"uid\\\":\\\"ll2.acc_727V8M6GjPJ9I26CqZHgxN\\\"}\\\"\\013\\022\\006ll2-cc\\032\\0019\" endorsement:<endorser:\"\\n\\007PASSKIT\\022\\224\\010>"
rawJSON := re.FindStringSubmatch(rawResponse)
```

Go Playground https://play.golang.org/p/XRfbExNa9V

Comment: Are you trying to achieve [this](https://play.golang.org/p/t6lvYq6Kb-)?

Comment: Using regular expressions instead of parsing is always bad idea.

Comment: Not quite.  Your example returns `{\"id\":\"ll2.card_4U45pAWUMCLhsu\",\"uid\":\"ll2.acc_727V8M6GjPJ9I26CqZHgxN\"}\"\013\022\006ll2-cc\032\0019`, I just need `{\"id\":\"ll2.card_4U45pAWUMCLhsu\",\"uid\":\"ll2.acc_727V8M6GjPJ9I26CqZHgxN\"}`

Comment: @GrzegorzŻur I agree, but in this particular case parsing is not an option

Comment: @PassKit: Well, it is not a valid JSON... So, you need to get the values of 2 fields, `id` and `uid`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Adapting your playground got me to the result. 
 https://play.golang.org/p/mFYLwa2ki0.  If you post as an answer I will accept.  I understand the JSON is not valid, but that can parsed.

Comment: Note: If any of the values contain `}` the accepted solution won't work.

Comment: Regex will pattern which string in memory , not the plain text we see.
it's `payload:"{` not `payload:\"{`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this: ( [Run here](http://ideone.com/ncDO0t) )

```
package main

import (
    "regexp"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`payload:\\"(\{[^\}]+\})`)
    var str = `version:1 response:<status:200 message:\"OK\" payload:\"{\\\"id\\\":\\\"ll2.card_4U45pAWUMCLhsu\\\",\\\"uid\\\":\\\"ll2.acc_727V8M6GjPJ9I26CqZHgxN\\\"}\\\"\\013\\022\\006ll2-cc\\032\\0019\" endorsement:<endorser:\"\\n\\007PASSKIT\\022\\224\\010>`
    rawJSON := re.FindStringSubmatch(str)
    fmt.Println(rawJSON[1])    
}
```